# Load view classes dynamically in Play using reflection in java

Tags: java, scala, reflection, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've a configuration file from which I want to read the name of the view and then render the view. I'm trying to use java reflection for this and code looks something like:

```
Class viewClass = Play.current().classloader().loadClass(viewName);
Method render = viewClass.getDeclaredMethod("render");
page = (Html)render.invoke(viewClass.newInstance());
```

I'm getting Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. viewName is the name of the view.

Comment: What are you using as `viewName` (ie the value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't posted how you obtained a class name so I presents a full example in this case for an *index* view.

```
String viewName = "views.html.index"
Class viewClass = Play.current().classloader().loadClass(viewName);
Method render = viewClass.getDeclaredMethod("render");
Html page = (Html) render.invoke(null);
```

There's another problem that you can't call the **newInstance()** method for a view class. Luckily you don't need an instance of a class as the **render()** method can be called statically. Just pass a null to the **invoke()** method.